# If $ab \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$, $p$ prime, why is $b \in {1, 2, ..., p-1}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> **Fact**: If $ax\equiv1 \pmod{p}$, $p$ prime, and $\beta$ a solution, then $\beta\in\{1,\dots, p-1\}$.

It's a result assumed naturally in a proof of Wilson's theorem, but I can't see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you say need not be true; for example, $2\cdot 14 = 28\equiv 1\mod{3}$, yet $28\notin \{1,2\}$. It is always possible to choose $b$ such that this is the case, however, by adding or subtracting multiples of $p$ so that $b$ is in the range $\{0, 1, \dotsc, p-1\}$ (in the example above, $2\cdot 28 \equiv 2\cdot (28-9\cdot 3) = 2\cdot 1$). Then since $b\ne 0$, the result follows.

If the original formulation is considering elements of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, then the statement is true (but as you asked the question, it sounds like you're talking about $\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: Thank you! I think the book I'm using (it's in portuguese so I don't cared about citing it here) is treating integers as classes of equivalence modulo p.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose this is not the case then $\beta=0$, hence $$0 \equiv 1 \mod p$$ which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

$$ab\equiv 1(\mod p)$$ means $a=b^{-1}$. In particular, $b$ is invertible, so $b\in (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times=\{1,\dots, p-1\}$.